# All combinations of a list into an infinite list in haskell

Tags: haskell

My task is to implement a function `allCombinations`, in Haskell, which returns every possible combination of a given list as an infinite list.

Since i couldn't find a solution, which does not include imports, i will ask it again.
I'm new to Haskell and my task is to create a function `allCombinations :: [a] -> [[a]]`, which creates an infinite list of possible combinations. For Example: `take 10 (allCombinations [True,False])`,
in return I should get `[[],[True],[False],[True,True],[False,True],[True,False],[False,False],[True,True,True],[False,True,True],[True,False,True]]`.
I have found a few solutions, but all of them included imports and i need to solve this without any imports.

Comment: So you want combinations of every possible length, starting at 0. Assume you've managed to write (for example, using recursion on len) a magic function `fn` such that `fn xs len` gives you all combinations of exactly `len` elements taken from list xs. Then a solution would be: `allCombinations xs = concatMap (\n -> fn xs n) [0..]` or in shorter form: `allCombinations xs = concatMap (fn xs) [0..]`. And library function `concatMap` is part of the Haskell Prelude, so does not require an import clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with recursion here. This starts with the empty list, and then you recurse where you prepend with the given list, and the items in the list, so:

```
allCombinations :: [a] -> [[a]]
allCombinations xs = zs
  where zs = [] : [ (y:ys) | ys <- zs, y <- xs ]
```